# MOSS 2007 - Parent Folder Column

Tags: sharepoint

I use a flat document list for certain document types and I want to give my users a possiblity to jump to the parent folder of this document.

Is there a column that contains this information? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a column or UI affordance for the parent folder in either a document library or the document library web part, nor is there a way to create a calculated field (without creating a totally custom field in code) - MSFT intended people to use the breadcrumbs I suppose.  There *are* plenty of third party web parts out there for sale that provide this functionality (sort of) -but I haven't found one yet that I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something [like this](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2008/11/03/adding-an-up-folder-button-to-a-sharepoint-list-view-webpart.aspx) you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. I was looking for a field type, so that every item can have link to it's parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find an easy solution for my problem, I just coded that field type myself.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is nothing OOTB that provides this information. At best, you can 'guess' the parent folder by getting the second-to-last segment of the FileRef column (the file's own URL):

```
                     ▼ this one
/web/web/list/folder/folder/file.ext
```

Of course, that only works when you can have a reasonable expectation the file will actually be at least one folder deep. We have some limited cases where this works.